# Make a multipart export / import with loaddata and dumpdata in django

Tags: json, django

So i made a dumpdata with django but my file is really big.

Does anyone have any tip on how to make a multi part export and import with dumpdata and loaddata in django ?

I have mainly an app that take the most size so i can separate by app.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: import is easy. Just open the file and divide it into two or three parts. Its basically json

Answer (score 1):

based on @Arpit Solanki answer, finally I used the following script to export:

```
import subprocess
from django.apps import apps
for model in apps.get_models():
    model_str = f'{model._meta.app_label}.{model.__name__}.json'
    print(model_str)
    subprocess.call(['python', 'manage.py', 'dumpdata', '--indent', '2', '-o', f'{model_str}.json', model_str])
```

of course, the **'--indent', '2'** parameter is optional. This script requires Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This could be kind of complicated but i will try for simple.
first you need to list out all the models in your app.

```
for model in django.apps.apps.get_models():
    print(model.__name__)
    subprocess.call('python', 'manage.py', 'dumpdata', model.__name__)
```

You can modify this `subprocess.call` according to your needs whether you want to store it in a file or whatever. Like you can save a model's data into a file.

```
>>> python manage.py dumpdata app._name.model_name > model_name_dump.json
```

In the same way you can also use `loaddata`. Below is an example of json dump:

```
[
  {
    "model": "app.user",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$30000$1LwvC3DJb6RI$P4nYQK/9UyDEiZpEJjfl0SATBiL5l8dRZ61QE83TzS4=",
      "last_login": "2017-06-09T11:41:26Z",
      "email": "SOLANKIARPIT1997@GMAIL.COM",
      "is_active": true,
      "is_account_active": true,
      "first_name": "arpit",
      "last_name": "solanki",
      "created_at": "2017-06-09T11:40:59Z",
      "is_superuser": false,
      "groups": [
        2
      ],
      "user_permissions": []
    }
  }
  {
    "model": "app.user",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "password": "pbkdfjgkf2_sha256$30000$1LwvC3DJb6RI$P4nYQK/9UyDEiZpEJjfl0SATBiL5l8dRZ61QE83TzS4=",
      "last_login": "2017-06-09T11:41:26Z",
      "email": "SOLANKRPIT1997@GMAIL.COM",
      "is_active": true,
      "is_account_active": true,
      "first_name": "arpit",
      "last_name": "solnki",
      "created_at": "2017-06-09T11:40:59Z",
      "is_superuser": false,
      "groups": [
        2
      ],
      "user_permissions": []
    }
  }
. .
. .
]
```

Its also pretty easy to split a json dump into multiple small file as it has a very fix structure.

Comment: I have also one model that take 90% of the space :/ but thanks

Comment: do one thing open that file in a good text editor like sublime and use json beautifier upon it. You will be able to see the structure of the json then you will know that its pretty easy to write a script which splits your big file into small files

Comment: @user462794 is it better now or you still need something else.

Comment: my json file is 6 gigas :/ so i can't edit it simply

Comment: you can still open your file using a python script load the data and copy it into multiple files. By the way you should provide a clear scenario in your problem description